# Styling issues when using jquery mobile and google maps -- needs refresh to fit

Tags: css, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I started writing my mobile site and I encountered the following problem:

When I first load the index page, and click on maps page, then [image: I see only one small part] (top left) occupied by google maps. But if I load maps page `directly`, it loads correctly:

Again: if I go directly to page with maps, it works great!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggrEH/7/

Comment: How do you load the map page, you bind it to with event? If you bind it to `pageinit`, instead bind it to `pagebeforeshow`, e.g. `document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]#maps' , function(){}`

Comment: jsFiddle, link to site??

Comment: Wrap the above code with this `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]#maps', function() { //map code here });`. Remove `onload` from body.

Comment: I added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggrEH/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile, by default the pages are loaded through AJAX. That's the difference between opening the page directly and through navigation. It is recommended to use a jQuery Mobile event to initialize the map.

I've modified your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Map Example Multiple Pages</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps</title>
        <meta content="en" http-equiv="content-language">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <style>
            #map_canvas{
                padding-top:0px;
                padding-bottom:-1px;
                padding-left:0px;
                height:auto;
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:95%;
                max-height:1600px;
                max-width:1600px;
                overflow:hidden;
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
                var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278),
                myOptions = {
                    zoom:10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: mapCenter
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            }

            $(document).on("pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
                if ($("#map_canvas").html() === '') {
                    initialize();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home-page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Maps</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#map-page" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">Click to see the Map</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="map-page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Map</h1>
                <a href="#home-page" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; max-height:1600px;">
                <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED:**

Example based on the provided jsfiddle

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Map Example Multiple Pages</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps</title>
        <meta content="en" http-equiv="content-language">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <style>
            .map_canvas{
                padding-top:0px;
                padding-bottom:-1px;
                padding-left:0px;
                height:auto;
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:95%;
                max-height:1600px;
                max-width:1600px;
                overflow:hidden;
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script>
            var map, geocoder, initCenter;
            function initialize() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                initCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97);
                var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278),
                myOptions = {
                    zoom:10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: mapCenter
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps1"), myOptions);
            }

            $(document).on("pageshow", "#maps", function() {
                if ($("#googlemaps1").html() === '') {
                    initialize();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home" data-role="page" data-title="Home">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="vs_header">
                 <h1>Home</h1>
                <a href="#maps" data-icon="info">maps</a> 
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="index-page">
                <div>
                    <p>dsfgsjdg dskfjgskdfsdbf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Page: maps -->
        <div id="maps" data-role="page" data-title="Fleet">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="vs_header" data-dom-cache="false">
                 <h1>Fleet</h1>
                <a href="#home" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
            </div>
            <!-- header -->
            <div data-role="content" id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; max-height:1600px;">
                <div id="googlemaps1" class="map_canvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you explain? Which unnecessary step do you mean? Thanks

Comment: Please disregard; I understand what you are suggesting. Nevertheless, after I initialize the maps, it still having the same issues.

Comment: The trick is to initialize the map inside the $(document).on("pageshow", "#maps", function() {// initialize here }); Did you try to perform the initialization on pageshow?

Comment: I tried to implement on pageshow http://jsfiddle.net/ggrEH/13/ ; it did not work somehow

Comment: I've updated the answer. I've modified the code you provided on jsfiddle so that it works. In order to test it, put it inside a file ex: map.html and open it. The configuration on your jsfiddle is wrong since you're executing the JavaScript on load. Thanks

Comment: Implemented here as well in case that helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/tolis/WG4XG/